# Where is the "Additional Parking" at the Cross Border Xpress (CBX, on the San Diego side)?

Tags: usa, borders, automobiles, mexico, tij

I read on https://www.crossborderxpress.com/en/parking:

> Additional Parking - $15 USD

Where is the "Additional Parking" in [CBX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_Border_Xpress)?

At first I thought the "Additional Parking" may be the unlabeled parking lots on the following diagram, from the same webpage:

[image]

However, looking at [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Cross+Border+Xpress+CBX/@32.5502825,-116.9740518,876m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x80d947d2ae2fb653:0x34c41ca96c918788!8m2!3d32.5482076!4d-116.9745563), some of these unlabeled lots are mostly empty:

[image]

And there are many parking lots nearby as well.

Comment: Did you try contacting them?  There's a facebook page and email address listed on the FAQ for parking.  https://www.crossborderxpress.com/en/faq

Comment: @Midavalo  I eventually parked on the Mexican side. I'll ping them when I get a chance.